# Node.js Discord Bot : TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want my public bot to sendMessage in specific channel, and specific server. But, I have an error... this is my code:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('+specifictest')) {
    var channellog = msg.client.channels.get('352496750327496725');
    var guiiild = msg.client.guilds.get('343913599686934539').channellog;
    guiiild.send({
      embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setColor("#FFFFFF")
                        .setAuthor("Dessin")
                        .setDescription(`Demandé par <@${msg.author.id}>`)
    })
  }
})
```

And, my error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
client.channels.get("ID").send("Your message")
```

**ID** would be the id of the channel you want to send the message to. So in your case, try:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('+specifictest')) {
    client.channels.get("352496750327496725").send({embed: new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#FFFFFF").setAuthor("Dessin").setDescription(`Demandé par <@${msg.author.id}>`)})
  }
})
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)[discord](/questions/tagged/discord)[send](/questions/tagged/send)[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)[typeerror](/questions/tagged/typeerror)

Answer (score 2):

This might be late, but
try using `await`

I think you're using Disord v11 not 12, I would recommend upgrade to 12 but that's your decision

V11

```js
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('+specifictest')) {
    const channel = await client.channels.get("352496750327496725")
    channel.send({embed: new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#FFFFFF").setAuthor("Dessin").setDescription(`Demandé par <@${msg.author.id}>`)})
 }
})
```

v12

```js
client.on('message', async(msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('+specifictest')) {
    const channel = await client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id == "352496750327496725")
    channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("#FFFFFF").setAuthor("Dessin").setDescription(`Demandé par ${msg.author}`)}) //this is the same as <@ID>
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks bro you are a life safer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This error (in your context) means that your variable `guiiild` has not been correctly populated hence the unexpected failure when it tries to use an unexisting property (in this case the `send` function).

## Try/Catch

You can wrap it in a `try/catch block` :

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('+specifictest')) {
   try{
    var channellog = msg.client.channels.get('352496750327496725');
    var guiiild = msg.client.guilds.get('343913599686934539').channellog;
    guiiild.send({embed: new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#FFFFFF").setAuthor("Dessin").setDescription(`Demandé par <@${msg.author.id}>`)})
   }catch(e){console.log("[ERROR]",e)}
  }
})
```

But it will still give you errors if `msg.client.guilds.get('343913599686934539').channellog` doesnt return anything containing `.send`

Comment: I've try your code, and i've this error now:

[ERROR] TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

:c

Comment: @SplatingWorld, did you understand my answer? (its not only copy-paste)

Comment: Yeah, sorry... :c

Comment: Isn't channellog a function? Or isn't there something like guild.GetChannelLogs() instead?